# Recording HD from webcam using Expression encoder sdk in WPF

Tags: wpf, video-capture, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I am trying to record a stream from a webcam using Expression Encoder 4 SDK in WPF I can capture the video & audio streams and record these to disk however they are only recording at a base resolution of 320x240 the webcam is capable of capturing at 720p, how can I record at this resolution. Any help would be appreciated, I have been pulling my hair out trying to solve this all week.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is a bit late but all questions need answers:

These might be a possible solution:

- Check to see if your camera has it's own settings on the camera or comes with an installation disk.
- for the expression encoder 4 put the video profile quality to max.

Good luck. If you are still around tell me, how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

to change the "size" you can use the following line :

```
LiveJob.OutputFormat.VideoProfile.Streams[0].Size = new Size(1280,1080)
```

Or whatever you want it to be.

Encoder also offers a setting page that you can use.

That's what I did and then after setting the outputsize you can do that :

```
currentJob.OutputFormat.VideoProfile.Streams[0].Size = ((LiveSource)LiveDeviceSource).CropRect.Size;
```

Only 1 small limitation, you can't change the size while it's recording if you are publishing the source.